# Href link on input button submit

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, href

How can i bind this link

```
<a href="edit?id=<c:out value='${person.id}' />">
```

to  input button "submit" ?

Comment: your question is not clear..

Answer (score 0):

try something like that. Hope this will fix your problem

```
href="\edit?id={{person.id}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you are using a submit button, then you will be inside a form. An example of this would be:

```
<form action="edit?id=<c:out value='${person.id}' />" method="post">
    <!-- form fields here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In this case, the submit button is "tied" to the form, and will post the form data to the link in the `action` value.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :

```
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="${param.from}">
```

Servlet.class

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("from"));
```